# Multiple services via a single static IP

Tags: networking, ip

I'm looking to have the following setup -

2 "identical" web servers hosting the same websites, for redundancy.

A development server to be accessed remotely via VPN and not otherwise internet facing. I intend to use this dev server as the VPN server also, unless someone can give me a good reason not to, i.e instead use a dedicated VPN server.

A mail server.

A file server.

That's five servers.

I only want the web servers and the mail server to be internet facing and everything else accessed via the VPN.

Now, I have a single static IP address. How do I achieve the above?

For clarification, I am only looking for help regarding the access to the above setup via a single static IP address, not anything else to do with this set up.

Comment: Do you have some kind of gateway device? Which device would have the static IP?  What is the private network topology like?

Comment: I am using the supplied Vodafone Wi-Fi router, with my home broadband service. The internal network is statically assigned IPs - 192.168.x.x etc for the servers on the router. The only network device is this router and it has the static external IP.

Comment: Is everything internally on a different 192.168.x.x IP? ex - 192.168.1.10 = mail, .11 = file, .12 = site1 etc or is everything on the same local IP using different ports

Comment: All servers have a different static IP internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoudn't be a problem (except for the redundant webserver, this might be a bit more tricky)

It also looks like you are using NAT for your network (to connect different machines/NICs with their "private" IPs to the internet over your static "public" IP). Then you need to use port forwarding. If your servers run on different machines you need to forward to the right port and to the right IP as well.

You need to make sure the different servers/services will listen on different ports (if they are on one machine) which different services do anyway if you use the standard ports. That's about it.

The only problem will be the redundant webservers, they can't be both listening on the same port. Unless you can use a non-standard port on your web-backupserver and change it to the standard port 80 if the main server fails. There are loads of different solutions for that, depending on what you are/want to use (maybe your webserver already has those capabilities or you could use e.g. VMware with automatic failover and possibly load distribution when both servers are active).

This answer gives you a broad overview, the setup will be more complicated in detail. To tell the truth, it would be helpful to ask the redundancy aspect into a second question. It's not good to put to many problems/questions into one single question and there are too many approaches to this problem and needs much more detail which isn't relevant for the other problems.

Comment: I have a static external IP for my router, 83.x.x.x, I requested this from Vodafone, my ISP. I have a web server that serves web sites from that IP. I want to add another one for redundancy. I also want to host my own mail server for email for my own domain. And I want to use a dev server and file server but I only want to access these from the internet via a VPN.

Comment: Essentially I want to have two web servers on the same IP and a mail server (or two, again for redundancy (if this is the only way to guarantee 99.999 uptime) and still access my local network via VPN all on the same internet IP.

Comment: @norfolk_uk Ok, then it will be mainly the using the "ip/port forward" to the individual machines where the servers/services run on. I updated my answer slightly for the redundancy issue. Do you want your webserver to be used by everyone or just by you?

Comment: The web servers are hosting publicly available web sites.

Comment: @norfolk_uk Then I would suggest you get your system up and running without the redundant webserver first, and then isolate the web server redundancy issue in a second question. It's not good to put too many problems into one question.